# Xml deserialize does unwanted initialization

Tags: c#, constructor, xmlserializer

I have a class which contains a list. In its constructor I add a default object to the list.

```
class A
{
   List<B> list;
   public A()
   {
       list = new List<B>();
       B b = new B();
       list.Add(b);
   }
}
```

But it seems when `XmlSerializer` deserialize the XML file containing the `A` object, the loaded object have two `B` object in its list. I guess it calls the constructor again and the constructor adds the next `B`

Why it happens? How can I avoid it?

Comment: When it deserializes it calls the `default constructor`, which in your case adds a `B` object. **Then** it reforms all the *properties* to their deserialized values, meaning it adds a *second* `B` object (with `list.Add`). Your constructor should **not** be adding an element to the list like that if you want to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try an overloaded constructor.  One takes nothing and adds nothing to the list, which is what can be used when deserializing.  The other takes a B and adds B to the list.